# Boot CD for ia64

Tags: boot, itanium, rescue-disk

I'm looking for rescue or live CDs for Itanium servers, but the only bootable CDs I've found are the distros installation CDs. Mainly I want to clone the servers disks, and also check memory or disk bad blocks. I've tried with the same CDs I use on x86-64 but none of them have a version for ia64.
Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the Debian text installer has a "rescue mode" giving you a shell with a handful of useful commands. It is not as comprehensive as SysRescueCD, but hey, it's precompiled for ia64. I believe Gentoo has something similar. There also is a `memtest` binary for ia64, but I do not know if it is part of the rescue mode shell as well.

Comment: Debian 6.0.3 installer in rescue mode worked fine for cloning disks (I needed badblocks and dd mainly). "fdisk -l" didn't work but "cat /proc/partitions" did

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old-school, but there's the [Gentoo live CD build for ia64](http://ftp.dei.uc.pt/pub/linux/gentoo/experimental/ia64/livecd/) from 2007.